# Breaking up a large "monolithic" class into smaller ones

Tags: oop, uml, structure

What is the best way to go about breaking up a large "monolithic" class into smaller ones?

I have designed a simple chat system that has `User` objects and `Channel` objects, where a user can be in and talk in a number of channels.

Here is a diagram of my design:

[image: UML chat design diagram]

The primary issue I have with this design is that the `ChatManager` class is a bit monolithic, i.e. it does too many things. In a previous incarnation it also handled channel membership, which has now been separated out in to `ChannelMembershipManager`.

What is the best way to go about "simplifying" my `ChatManager` class? Are there any other problems with my design I am not seeing?

Comment: seems reasonable. top level manager classes tend to be a bit ugly.

Comment: Yeah, I asked on reddit and sadly got the same response. I was just hoping there was something I could to do tidy it up.

Comment: nothing is obviously wrong with the diagrams. code it up and look for chances to refactor.

Comment: It's a shame people still think key object orientation tenets are opinions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to break up that monolithic manager is to assign responsibilities to the classes, according to OO tenets. Here are some suggestions that immediately come to mind. Don't expect perfection, this is just off the top of my head.

I see no need for a "Manager" class, although I *do* see a need to track all the instances of the `Channel` class and all the instances of the `User` class. *Maybe* this could be done with class statics within each class. (These indexes could be modeled in UML using *qualifiers*, which work kind of like hash maps. The `Channels` and `Users` really don't even need numbers! Those numbers are merely one of many ways to code this.

Each instance of the `User` class can use a command channel to communicate with a person. When a person asks the instance of the `User` class to join a channel, it can create an instance of a `Private Channel` that manages a per-channel socket that is private to one person, then ask an instance of the requested `Channel` for permission to accept it. That `Private Channel` could have methods to `poll()`, `read()` and `write()`.

An instance of a `Channel` class chould be responsible for announcing things when a `User` joins or leaves. Each instance of a `Channel` class should be responsible for polling the connected `Private Channel` instances, reading messages / commands, and taking action, such as repeating a message out to all the other `Private Channels`.

This is just off the top of my head. If I took some time to think about it, I might see some potential problems or optimizations I could make, but hopefully this gives you some ideas for how to split up a "manager" monolith according to OO tenets.